# «Домашних детей» или «домашние дети» - падеж в контексте?

Tags: склонение

> Но с другой стороны, «домашних детей» — их видно всегда.

Comment: Зависит от контекста. Например. С одной стороны уличные дети, они незаметны. С другой стороны — «домашние дети», их видно всегда.

Comment: Скорее всего, не это автор имел в виду, но что?

Comment: Может так: С одной стороны, "домашние дети" тихие. Но с другой стороны, «домашних детей» — их видно всегда. Сойдет как разговорная речь, но не более того.

Comment: Продвинутость детей, воспитуемых с няньками, гувернёрами, учителями того-сего, с секциями, кружками и т. д. "Их видно" по манэээрам и познаниям, по развитой речи, по лексическому запасу... Кстати о птицах. Это такая разговорная речь, что разговорнее не бывает: это интервью.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если "с другой стороны" — о детях, то:

*Но с другой стороны, «домашние дети» — их видно всегда.*

Здесь *домашние дети* — именительный темы.

А если "с другой стороны" — о том, что их видно всегда, тогда:

**Но с другой стороны, «домашних детей» — их видно всегда.**

Здесь *домашние дети* управляются глаголом *видно*.

Вероятно, имелось в виду последнее.

Comment: Первое-распрепервое!!! И НИ-КА-ДА, даже за рупь, не поминай при мне "именительный темы"! Я сугубый практик! У меня в школе была единица по русскому, а в институте тройка! Не знаю я ваших терминов и теорий!!!